# Compilation problem with EnumTools in Haxe Language

Tags: haxe

I'm trying to compile a simple hello world program, but then I get the following error:

> /usr/share/haxe/std/haxe/EnumTools.hx:50: characters 44-51 : Type name Main is redefined from module Main
>   Any ideas?

Comment: Please add some detail on haxe version and possibly the Main.hx file for reference. Also might be worth checking [try haxe](https://try.haxe.org/) to see if its something to do with your local setup or the code.

Answer (score 2):

It was a problem that I had two .hx files(which both had the same Main class) in the same directory, when I tried to compile the error was not so clear